# Xpath noob: querying an xml element using xpath and a unique attribute?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am querying a particularly ugly HTML file using xpath.  I want to extract an HTML table that is buried deep within the document.  However instead of going down through the hierarchy from //html/, is there anyway I can just reference the table's unique id attribute?

Obviously this would have far less chance of breaking due to page edits too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
descendant::*[@id='whatever']
```

If the "ID" was not unique, you will get a list of all matching nodes.

Comment: Alternatively, `//*[@id='whatever']` will do the same job. But I don't want to take away from mihi's good answer. +1

Comment: wouldn't that just pull out the id only when it is equal to 'whatever'? I thought he was asking how to get the id attribute regardless of it's value.

Comment: thanks - and if it was unique amongst div elements could I get a match via '//div[@id="datafiles"]' ?

Comment: no they guessed correct - but I can see the confusion.  I wanted to use xpath to get a table/div element with a specified id

Comment: @rutherford: You're correct about the `//div[@id='datafiles']` question.

Comment: `//*` is not the same as `descendant::*` - `//` means `descendant-or-self::node()` - http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116#path-abbrev

Comment: but `//*/*` is still shorter than `descencant::*` :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also just use:

```
//table[@id='yourId']
```

The // matches the element anywhere in the document, the 'table' matches only table elements and the filter (between the square brackets) only retrieves the element with your id.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
xpath.evaluate("/html/body/table[@id]");
```

It's been a while since I used xpath so that not may be exactly correct but it's close.

Comment: ChadNC, you are close. That will only match a table that is a direct child of the body element that contains an attibute named "id". What you want is something like what mihi (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744651/xpath-noob-querying-an-xml-element-using-xpath-and-a-unique-attribute/1744694#1744694) said. Or xpath.evaluate("//table[@id = 'tableId']") where 'tableId' is the unique id being searched for.

Comment: roger that. That was just meant to be a simple example that would only find exactly what you said it would. I figured he/she could adjust it to thier specific needs. But I hadn't thought about just using "//table[@id='tableid']" which I think I'll be putting to use fairly soon :)